# Can't boot ubuntu, not even in safe mode

Tags: 12.04, boot, nvidia, grub2, fstab

At first I couldn't even access the grub menu. Booted from Live CD and repaired that with the grub repair tool.

Now when I try to boot normal, I get the purple screen thing.

I tried the `nomodeset` thing and its not working anymore. A few days ago I had the same problem and it worked when I put `nomodeset` instead of `quiet splash`..

If I try to boot in recovery mode, I get a dialog, and any option I choose from the menu (resume, dpkg, or the option without graphics support) I get another dialog saying:

> Continuing will remount your / filesystem in read/write mode and mount
>   any other filesystem defined in /etc/fstab

If I click OK, I get

> mountall: mount /home/...../Desktop/access [1219] terminated with
>   status 32

and that's it.

The mount worked OK until now, everything was OK, apart from the `nomodeset` thing after I made some Ubuntu updates...

Last thing i did this morning i edited something to the grub file, so I don't need to always edit `nomodeset`... But even after that the system started..

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed on a asus u36s notebook. No nvidia drivers installed. The notebook has the optimus graphics thing, but I didn't install bumblebee. Don't really need the nvidia graphics...

UPDATE:

I managed to boot from a live cd and mounted the hardrive and edited /etc/default/grub back to initial and also edited /etc/fstab back to initial state.

After this i still cant boot ubuntu in normal mode, with/without nomodeset in grub menu.
And when i boot in recovery mode, i get the console, i log with my account and after 1-2 mins i just get a black screen and nothing happening.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by editing `/etc/default/grub` back to initial and also edited `/etc/fstab` back to initial state and then I went to the BIOS and enabled UEFI boot.

Now it seams to be mostly OK. Getting the purple screen sometimes.... but I just reboot and it works.